# Can't call forEach on model hash in controller

Tags: arrays, ember.js, controller, computed-properties

I have a route called `tickets` which has it's model setup like so

```
model() {
  return Ember.RSVP.hash({
    event: null,
    tickets: null
  });
},
actions: {
  didTransition(){
    if(!this.controller.get('model.length')){
      new Ember.RSVP.hash({
        event: this.modelFor('events.event'),
        tickets: this.store.query('ticket',{user_id:this.get('user.user.user_id'),event_code:this.modelFor('events.event').get('event_code')})
      }).then((hash)=>{
        if(!hash.tickets.get('length')){
          this.controller.set('noTickets',true);
        }
        this.controller.set('model',hash);
      });
    }
  }
}
```

The template manages to loop over these `model.tickets` just fine in a `{{#each}}` block

In my controller I'm attempting to setup a `groupBy` computed, but in my computed is where I get the error

```
ticketsByPurchase: Ember.computed('model.tickets.[].ticket_purchase_code',function(){
    let tickets = this.get('model.tickets');
    tickets.forEach(function(ticket){
      console.log(ticket);
    });
  })
```

Comment: You likely will want to use `@each` instead of `[]` in your dependent property.  `model.tickets.@each.ticket_purchase_code`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try guarding against the model.tickets being iterated over, with something like this in the computed property:

```
if(!tickets){
  return Ember.A()
}else{
  //your forEach code here
}
```

or this in your route:

```
  }).then((hash)=>{
    if(!hash.tickets.get('length')){
      this.controller.set('noTickets',true);
      hash.tickets = Ember.Array([])
      this.controller.set('model',hash);
    }else{
      this.controller.set('model',hash);
    }
  });
```

Comment: You don't need to wrap the `[]` in `Ember.Array`, Ember by default extends Array to implement `Ember.Enumerable`, `Ember.MutableEnumerable`, `Ember.MutableArray` and `Ember.Array` interfaces.  https://guides.emberjs.com/v1.10.0/configuring-ember/disabling-prototype-extensions/

Comment: Link to newer Ember for prototype: https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.5.0/configuring-ember/disabling-prototype-extensions/

Answer (score 0):

`this.controller.get('model.length')` is always null because model is a hash, not an array. Also `didTransition` is not an action, it's a regular function, so it probably will not fire if defined in the actions hash.

I would recommend removing the call to didTransition and do all the logic in your model hook like so:

```
model() {
  let event = this.modelFor('events.event');
  let event_code = event.get('event_code');

  // this probably does not work, you have to get the user
  // from another route or a service.
  // this might work: this.controllerFor('user').get('user.user_id');
  let user_id = this.get('user.user.user_id');

  return Ember.RSVP.hash({
    event,
    tickets: this.store.query('ticket', { user_id, event_code })
  });
},

setupController(controller, model) {
  // super sets controller model to be route model.
  // ie. controller.set('model', model);
  this._super(...arguments);

  if (!model.get('tickets.length')) {
    controller.set('noTickets', true);
  }
}
```

Comment: `didTransition` is an event and does belong in the actions hash.  http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#event_didTransition .  The others are `activate`, `deactivate`, `error`, `loading`, `willTransition`